# I cannot move the camera anymore

Tags: camera

So, i cannot move the camera anymore with the G button.

Cannot even highlight it. Cannot click on it or select it with Select Box. Going into camera view and clicking the sides does not make me able to select and move the camera either.

**It only happens on one single .blend file.** Anyone have this problem?

Google does not get me any help so im trying my luck here. Hope to find a fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps you disabled its selectability [in the outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner/interface.html#restriction-columns) or in the [viewport's object type visibility popover](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/visibility.html).

In the outliner, open the Restriction Toggles popover and enable Selectablee (mouse pointer icon):

[image: selectable]

Make sure your camera's mouse icon is ON.

In the Viewport, make sure the same icon is enabled for the camera:

[image: vieport]

Comment: thanks LOLock! Turns out the entire collection had the mouse icon disabled. Weird never remember pressing it. So yeah that fixed it!